# How to run/execute in linux (say ./mycode) using matlab

Tags: linux, matlab

In Linux: I have executable file of my FORTRAN code (say ./mycode). which can be run using 
command: "./mycode < input1 > outputfile.out"  and it takes only 50 Sec to complete the run
Now i want to run this code many time with different input files (say input1, input2,..., input40 )
what should i do? i also want to save output separately. Is there any way to do this in linux,

## or

**can i use matlab to execute this "./mycode < input1 > outputfile1.out" command in linux?**
i tried in matlab using:

- cmd=sprintf('./mycode < input1 > outputfile.out')

  -[r,s]=system(cmd);

  -disp(s);

But i am stuck with an error: At line 28 of file somefile.f90 (unit = 5, file = 'fort.5')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Answer (score 2):

you can use a bash script, for example:

runOnMany.sh

```
for input in input1 input2 input3 ...
do
    outputExtension=".out"
    output=$input$outputExtension
     ./mycode $input $output
done
```

Or is there are hundreds, you can put the in a file and change the for expression to:

```
for i in input*
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.
But using this i cannot save output files separately

Comment: Do you mean you need them all in one file? Or they cant be separated form the input files?

Comment: no i want to save all output files.
Forexample if i want to move output1 to some folder so i need to wait atleast for 50 Sec. in each step in above loop than i can use move command

Comment: @Rizvi There you go, i edited the answer, now all of your output files will have the same name as the inputs but with `.out` on the end. This should solve your problem.